# Managing runtime dependencies in a maven reactor project

Tags: maven, dependencies, runtime, reactor

I have a maven reactor project with a rest module and a war module. The war module is a wrapper for the rest module along with the web.xml file. I am trying to understand if it's a good practice to maintain all the runtime dependencies in war module. For instance, if I am pulling in a dependency X (which has an interface X) in the rest module, I want to pull the runtime dependency of X as part of the war module. This way all the compile scoped dependencies are in the rest layer pom and all the runtime dependencies are in the war layer.

Note: I don't see a case where the rest layer will be pulled in by any other pom file other than the war project.

Can anyone see a problem with this approach? Am I missing anything that I would regret down the road?

Example:

Project A has two modules: project-rest and project-war. Project-war is a wrapper for the project-rest and has some web filters around authentication in the web.xml (there is no source code in this module).

Project-rest obviously has REST resources and makes calls to the service layer. The service layer is divided into different projects based on the implementations, project-service is the interface and project-service-hibernate is the implementation. As far as managing dependencies in project-rest, all I need is the compile-time dependencies for the project to build. I am planning to add the project-service dependency to the project-rest pom file and project-service-hibernate as a runtime dependency on the project-war pom file. The goal here is to separate out and manage all the runtime dependencies in the war module and the compile-time dependencies in the rest module.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. Can you add an example to the question? Why do you need the dependencies in both modules?

Comment: @JFMeier, provided an example. Please let me know if you need additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I would prefer to pack all the dependencies (both the runtime and the compile dependencies) into the rest module.

In this way, you see what compile and runtime dependencies belong together.

Especially, if the war has no source code, I would not add dependencies.